# Broadcast receiver not detecting SMS

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

I have a Broadcast Receiver which starts an activity on receiving SMS or  WIFI State Changed. It's detecting and working fine on WIFI State Change but not detecting SMS.

Here is my Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Registration of Broadcast Receiver

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
   <intent-filter android:priority="999">
     <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
     <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Java Code

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
  i.setClassName("my_package","my_package.class_name");
  i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  context.startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" android:exported="true">

Comment: Change <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver"> to full path of .MyReceiver , example com.example.MyReceiver

Comment: That could not be issue because Wifi State Change Broadcast is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that some other app is consuming the event. For example [GO SMS Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms) has priority set to `2^31-1 = 2147483647` and when not explicitly told not to, it prevents the event from propagation (aborts the broadcast).

Check your phone for any apps that handle SMS and try to disable them for testing purposes.